# error] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /Users/user/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna6522888454902179447.tmp

Tags: scala, playframework, java-11

I am new to Mac and Scala/Play-framework and trying to setup and run a webapp locally, but getting an error which I assume is an issue with the M1 silicone processor. Installing the webapp with `sbt dist` works fine, but when running it using command `run -Dconfig.file=./app.conf -Djdk.tls.trustNameService=true -Dhttps.port=8080 -Dhttp.port=8081` it gives a jna error. My system operative is Mac Monterey.

Full error:

```
[error] java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library:/Users/roozbeh.merandi/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna6522888454902179447.tmp
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2633)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:768)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.System.load(System.java:1837)
[error]     at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:1018)
[error]     at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:988)
[error]     at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:195)
[error]     at io.methvin.watchservice.jna.CarbonAPI.<clinit>(CarbonAPI.java:20)
[error]     at io.methvin.watchservice.jna.CFStringRef.toCFString(CFStringRef.java:23)
[error]     at io.methvin.watchservice.MacOSXListeningWatchService.register(MacOSXListeningWatchService.java:127)
[error]     at io.methvin.watchservice.WatchablePath.register(WatchablePath.java:50)
[error]     at io.methvin.watcher.DirectoryWatcher.register(DirectoryWatcher.java:400)
[error]     at io.methvin.watcher.DirectoryWatcher.registerAll(DirectoryWatcher.java:373)
[error]     at io.methvin.watcher.DirectoryWatcher.<init>(DirectoryWatcher.java:193)
[error]     at io.methvin.watcher.DirectoryWatcher$Builder.build(DirectoryWatcher.java:122)
[error]     at play.dev.filewatch.DefaultFileWatchService.watch(DefaultFileWatchService.scala:44)
[error]     at play.dev.filewatch.FileWatchService$$anon$1.watch(FileWatchService.scala:95)
[error]     at play.runsupport.Reloader.<init>(Reloader.scala:443)
[error]     at play.runsupport.Reloader$.reloader$lzycompute$1(Reloader.scala:283)
[error]     at play.runsupport.Reloader$.play$runsupport$Reloader$$reloader$1(Reloader.scala:275)
[error]     at play.runsupport.Reloader$.startDevMode(Reloader.scala:301)
[error]     at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$.devModeServer$lzycompute$1(PlayRun.scala:100)
[error]     at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$.devModeServer$1(PlayRun.scala:83)
[error]     at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$.$anonfun$playRunTask$3(PlayRun.scala:107)
[error]     at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$.$anonfun$playRunTask$3$adapted(PlayRun.scala:67)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / run for the full output
[error] (Compile / run) java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /Users/roozbeh.merandi/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna6522888454902179447.tmp
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnsatisfiedLinkError for M1 Macs while running Play server locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368863/unsatisfiedlinkerror-for-m1-macs-while-running-play-server-locally)

Comment: a solution to this issue was already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368863/unsatisfiedlinkerror-for-m1-macs-while-running-play-server-locally)

Comment: Solution was already provided here [UnsatisfiedLinkError for M1 Macs while running Play server locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368863/unsatisfiedlinkerror-for-m1-macs-while-running-play-server-locally)